# Does it make sense power-wise to put a smart plug inline with a laser printer?

Tags: electrical

I've seen people recommend putting printers behind a smart plug that can be turned on or off with a phone. Does this make sense power-wise? How much current does a printer in standby draw versus a typical smart plug like a WeMo?

Comment: There's a big, big difference between "printer" and "laser printer".   Inkjet printe

Comment: As I was saying before I was so [rudely interrupted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form), inkjet printers are so low-power most use wall-warts and some can be USB-powered. Laser printers use 400F heat to fuse toner, so they have a very powerful heater onboard. You can't put a laser printer and a gaming PC on the same 15A circuit, for instance.  While idling, lasers warm up their fuser periodically, so that big slam-draw can happen anytime.

Comment: Modern laser printers have multiple power modes and can be quite power efficient when not in use, the [Brother 3140](http://support.brother.com/g/b/spec.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=hl3140cw_us_eu)  is rated 1100W "peak", 335W "printing", 60W "ready", 6.5W "sleep", 0.5W "deep sleep", and 0.05W "off".  So, depending on how often you use the printer, it may use very little power.

Comment: Get yourself a device called a KillaWatt. These are an inline voltage/current/power meter that plugs into an outlet and then have an auxiliary outlet on the front to which you can attach an appliance such as your printer. With it you can get a first hand measurement of the power consumed by your printer in its active and idle states.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a matter of preference and opinion. In my opinion the amount of current being used is not significant enough to warrant turning them off for short periods of time (10 hours or less). It's always a good idea to shut everything down during long periods like when you're gone for the weekend or vacation.

In my opinion it's healthier to leave electronic equipment on since turning them off and on adds stress to the system. Think of an incandescent light. It burns out when changing state, usually off to on because the element is heating up and cooling off. It's not much different with electronic equipment.

By the way I own three printers a laser, an inkjet and a wide carriage and I really don't see appreciable utility usage.

All that being said, if you are traveling or for some reason you need to turn your stuff on/off from a remote location, it's certainly convenient to have the ability.

Hope this helps.